# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=24, Too many open files

Tags: java, multithreading, bash, centos, processbuilder

I am connecting `wmic` via terminal for every 5 seconds by using thread. But I got **"java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=24, Too many open files"** 
after 1 day.

Thread program:

```
    public void run() {     
    try {
        while (true) {

            if (isStopIssued()) {
                break;
            }
            setStatus("SLEEP");

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            if (isStopIssued()) {
                break;
            }
            setStatus("ACTIVE");

            process();

            if (isStopIssued()) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }       
}
```

Process Method:

```
private void process() {
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash");
    Process p = null;
    int exit = 0;
    BufferedWriter p_stdin = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    String inDir = inputDir + "/" + inputFile;
    String errDir = errorDir + "/" + errorFile;
    String outDir = outputDir + "/" + outputFile;
    logger.debug("[JWMILoader] - Input Directory ---> " + inDir);
    logger.debug("[JWMILoader] - Output Directory ---> " + outDir);
    logger.debug("[JWMILoader] - Error Directory ---> " + errDir);
    File inFile = new File(inDir);
    File errFile = new File(errDir);
    try {
        p = builder.redirectOutput(inFile).start();  **// Line Number : 194 **
        p = builder.redirectError(errFile).start();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
    // get standard input of shell

    p_stdin = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    // execute the desired command (here: wmic) n times
    try {
        // single execution
        p_stdin.write(wmiQuery);
        p_stdin.newLine();
        p_stdin.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    // finally close the shell by execution exit command
    try {
        p_stdin.write("exit");
        p_stdin.newLine();
        p_stdin.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            p_stdin.close();
            exit = p.waitFor();
            logger.debug("[JWMILoader] - WQL Query Successfully Executed. Process Exit ---> " + exit);

        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
if (p != null) {
                p.destroy();
            }
}
```

Exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=24, Too many open files
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at mavens.imlog.etl.loader.JWMILoader.remoteConnection(JWMILoader.java:194)
at mavens.imlog.etl.loader.JWMILoader.process(JWMILoader.java:156)
at mavens.imlog.etl.loader.JWMILoader.run(JWMILoader.java:64)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=24, Too many open files
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 3 more
```

I am using **CENT OS**.

Please friends help me, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You start processes twice,

1. First one running with output inFile,
2. Second one running with output inFile & error errFile

Was it your original intension?

```
try {
    p = builder.redirectOutput(inFile).**start()**;  **// Line Number : 194 **
    p = builder.redirectError(errFile).**start()**;
}
catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(this.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

And destroy only the last one created.

```
  if (p != null) {
            p.destroy();
  }
```

Fix this, and this should fix your error.

P.S.

Start it only once:

```
try {
    builder = builder.redirectOutput(inFile);
    p = builder.redirectError(errFile).start();
}
```

Comment: How can i fix it. I am using different Process (or) using same Process? Suppose i am using same process means, how can i destory it twice?

Comment: Start it only once:

    try {
        builder = builder.redirectOutput(inFile);
        p = builder.redirectError(errFile).start();
    }